# How to approach modeling this character?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

[image: soldier]
I'm new to 3D modelling, and am trying to model a solider that is wearing a helmet with gear, vest with gear, etc. I have made most of the head after at least 10-12 hours of modelling using sculpting only and it looks ok zoomed out, but when I zoom in you can see that the gear is not perfectly smooth, things that should be straight lines are not perfect straight lines etc.

I have heard that sculpting can be quicker than poly-modelling for complex shapes but it seems like some of this stuff really needed poly-modelling to be accurate. What's the correct approach to something like this, a masked head wearing a helmet? Is there a good approach to learning enough Blender that you can properly do this?

Comment: Hi and welcome :) Please [add images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/199791/edit) to your post, your title indicates that there should be one, and it will greatly help your Q be clearer. Thanks :)

Comment: your question is a bit too broad, if you are a beginner you should begin with modeling in my opinion, then when you'll have your character almost finished, duplicate your object, keep a low poly version somewhere, on the copy use sculpting to add some details like cloth wrinkles etc, then bake the normals